# Get the cart item quantity by item id in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

In WooCommerce, I have created a mini cart and I want the get the item quantity available in the current cart.

As i have tried this:

```
  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

      foreach($items as $item => $values) {
          $product_id = $values['product_id'];
          if ( $product_id == $id ){
            $product_qnty = $values['quantity'];
          }
          break;
      }
```

Is there any single function to get the cart item quantity by cart item ?

Comment: I have just maid an update now that will take care of Variable products (product variations) too (after some further testing)… Also if you want/like please you could upvote this answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you should look first in the [woocommerce template code cart/mini-cart.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.2/templates/cart/mini-cart.php) where you will find the official related code.

Note: The "item ID" is only available in WC_Orders items loop, but not in WC_Cart which is a "Cart item Key". So you are surely talking about the product ID. But if you look to the code of the official template cart/mini_cart you will need to use the `WC_Product` object instead of the `$product_id`…

So you can always build a custom function like *(with a **`$product`** argument, the WC_Product object)* that you can use in the corresponding template code or in your custom code:

```
function get_item_qty( $product ){
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
        // for variable products (product varations)
        $product_id = $product->get_parent_id();
        if( $product_id == 0 || empty( $product_id ) )
            $product_id = $product->get_id();

        if ( $product_id == $cart_item['product_id'] ){
            return $cart_item['quantity'];
            // break;
        }
    return;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

**USAGE** *(example)*: Here we will output the quantity of the **`$product`** *(`WC_Product` object)*:

```
// Output the quantity based on the $product object
echo __('Quantity'). ': ' . get_item_qty( $product );
```

---

Official Documentation: [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)